# @WebServlet - Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Tags: servlets, annotations, tomcat7

I have been trying to replicate a web application in my eclipse IDE (Version: Juno Service Release 2, Build id: 20130225-0426) by watching some tutorials for learning purpose. The servlets used in the web-app uses **@WebServlet** annotation instead of using web.xml. I am using Tomcat v7.0 in my local host as my server. After completing the web-app I am getting errors in my web-app.

> 1.@WebServlet - Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
>
> 2. Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

as the web-app is using List.

I tried to look into the annotation issue and came across several fixes provided in different answers:

1. setting Java compiler under project properties and checking the enable project specific settings and  setting JDK version to 1.7 in the drop down menu.
2. Tried to change web-app version entry in web.xml to 3.0 but I did not find any web.xml for my web-app. Tried "**Generate Deployment Descriptor stub**" under Java EE Tools, but no web.xml generated.

I have java version 1.8 installed in my system and also under preferences -> JAVA -> Installed JREs option , I have set jre1.8 pointing to jdk1.8 location.

Under Project Facets option. I see I am using Dynamic web module 3.1.

What changes I have to make so that I can use @WebServlet with Tomcat v7.0?

Comment: Can you check once In project properties->Java Build Path/Libraries tab make sure you have JRE System Library 6 ennvironment. or greater then this

Comment: Yes Anand....I checked it!! My jre system library is set to jre 1.8.0_25